Truenas pool configuration for 12 drives. Pros and cons
I need to choose proper layout for 12 drives pool.
Options are:
4 raidz vdevs x 3, no spares
3 raidz vdevs x 3, 3 spares
2 raidz vdevs x 5, 2 spares
2 raidz2 vdevs x 6, no spares

The choice is hard for me, so any pros and cons are greatly appreciated
Pool obvective:
2 types of load

intense parallel random read-write of small files.

Rare sequential reads or writes, not simultaneous


Performance is not an issue.
Backups are replicated on another server nightly.
Worst case - if pool destroyed there will be a loss of maximum 1 day of work, which will be remediated during 1 next month, so reliability is somewhat important. Definitely more than speed
All disks are 10T WD Ultrastar

This depends on desired performance and reliability. And type and size of disks. Take rebuild times into account. Overall, we can't answer based on facts unless it's very detailed.

Does this answer your question? RAID strategy - 8 1TB drives

@NikitaKipriyanov thanks for comment. Updated the question

intense parallel random read-write of small files — that's the worst workload for any erasure-coded RAID, especially for ZFS which avoids the write hole in all its RAIDZ variants at even greater expense of performance. Even if you think "it's not an issue", benchmark it, to be not surprised too much after entering the production.

It depend on the size of disks because if it's >4TB using RAIDZ is not recommended. RAIDZ2 is the minimum you should start.
If the speed  of array is not so big concern think about 11 disks in RAIDZ3 + spare. This will give you array with size 8x disk size and 3 disks with parity. Later you can create mountpoints and manage disk quotas if you need.

All disks are 10T WD Ultrastar. Why RaidZ is not recommended in this case? Is there any whitepaper on it? Quick googling did me nothing about this

@OlegDok, here is one reference about RAIDZ/RAID5 https://www.techtarget.com/searchstorage/definition/RAID-5-redundant-array-of-independent-disks

@OlegDok, another reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/storage/comments/fascry/raid_5_is_it_pointless_for_large_drives/

Read it and looks like Z2 is the proper option here. Also somewhere in sub-links I found the idea that 3-way mirrors also rocks. The advantage for truenas is that mirrors can be added and REMOVED from working pools that brings the recovery times for degraded pool into a new level. WDYT?

@OlegDok, with Z2 you have 2 "checksum" disks, array can survive 2 disks failure. With Z3 you have 3 disks survive. Check based on importance of the information what you want. And get in mind to rebuild info on spare disk can be long, > one day....
